# Test modifier keys in karma unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test something if both shift key and down key are pressed TOGETHER.

My Code:

```
if (evt.keycode == '40') {
    if (evt.shiftKey) {
        $scope.data.checked = true;
    }
}
```

So I wrote this:

```
var triggerKeydown = function(element, keyCode) {
      var evt = jQuery.Event("keydown");
      evt.keyCode = keyCode;
      element.trigger(evt);
};
```

and ran this on the test:

```
triggerEvent.triggerKeydown(element, 40); // down key
triggerEvent.triggerKeydown(element, 16); //shift key
expect(element).toHaveClass('checked');
```

but the issue is that they get triggered one by one instead of together. How can I call both of them together?

Comment: The question misses the code that is tested. It is crucial here, because it is not clear what you test. Generally you may want to test It by stubbing jQuery methods, not by emulating the behaviour of a real user (save this for e2e test). It has Angular tag but doesn't have jQuery tag, which is primary here.

Comment: so if down is pressed and i m holding shift... it will change the objects property to true... im checking if the class for selected is there. Since i have a ng-class in the markup to have selected class on the element if its checked. Modified the code @estus

Comment: `My Code` doesn't contain enough code. What you're trying to do is functional test. I would suggest to save this for e2e test and stick to testing the code itself in unit tests.